# Flickr API - getting raw tags

Tags: jquery, flickr

I'm trying to modify a [jQuery library](https://github.com/rpheath/jquery-flickr) that streamlines communication with Flickr API to get to [raw versions](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.tags.getListUserRaw.html) of Flickr Tags, rather than [clean/machine-readable versions](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.tags.getListUser.html).

The below [excerpt](https://github.com/djsmith/jquery-flickr/blob/dc6bc990b812b4db3b9bf06ba4ab1f96490a1c73/jquery.flickr.js) of the library is responsible for getting clean tags using `flickr.tags.getListUser` method:

```
  // handles requesting list of tags

  $.flickr.tags = function(method, options, select) {
    var options = $.extend($.flickr.settings, options || {}),
          elements = $.flickr.self, tags

    return elements.each(function() {
      $.getJSON($.flickr.url(method, options), function(data) {
        var list = $.flickr.tags.selectList(data.who.tags, select);
        elements.append(list);
      })
    })
  }

  // converts tags into select list.

  $.flickr.tags.selectList = function(tags, options) {

    var optionList = $.map(tags.tag, function(tag) {
      return ['<option value="' + tag._content + '">' + tag._content + '</option>']
    }).join("\n")

    var selectList = $('<select class="flickr"></select>');
    if (options.multiple === true)
      selectList.attr('multiple', 'multiple');
    if (options.size !== undefined && options.size > 0)
      selectList.attr('size', options.size);
    if (options.prompt !== undefined && options.prompt != '')
      selectList.append('<option value="" selected="selected">' + options.prompt + '</option>');
    if (typeof(options.onchange) === 'function')
      selectList.change(options.onchange);

    return selectList.append(optionList)
  }

  // namespace to hold available API methods

  $.flickr.methods = {
    // http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.tags.getListUser.html

    tagSelect: function(options, select) {
      $.flickr.tags('flickr.tags.getListUser', options, select)
    }
  }
```

So far, I have been unsuccessful in modification of the above to use `flickr.tags.getListUserRaw` method. The difference between the two methods is how tags are being returned:

For `flickr.tags.getListUser` tags are returned like this:

```
<who id="12037949754@N01">
  <tags>
    <tag>gull</tag>
    <tag>tag1</tag>
    <tag>tag2</tag>
    <tag>tags</tag>
    <tag>test</tag>
  </tags>
</who>
```

And for `flickr.tags.getListUserRaw` tags are returned like this:

```
<who id="12037949754@N01">
  <tags>
    <tag clean="foo">
      <raw>foo</raw>
      <raw>Foo</raw>
      <raw>f:oo</raw>
    </tag>
  </tags>
</who>
```

So, I've modified the code like this:

```
  // handles requesting list of tags

  $.flickr.tags = function(method, options, select) {
    var options = $.extend($.flickr.settings, options || {}),
          elements = $.flickr.self, tags

    return elements.each(function() {
      $.getJSON($.flickr.url(method, options), function(data) {
        var list = $.flickr.tags.selectList(data.who.tags, select);
        elements.append(list);
      })
    })
  }

  // converts tags into select list.

  $.flickr.tags.selectList = function(tags, options) {

    var optionList = $.map(tags.tag, function(tag) {
      return ['<option value="' + tag.attr('clean') + '">' + tag.raw._content + '</option>']
    }).join("\n")

    var selectList = $('<select class="flickr-tags" data-placeholder="Choose a tag..."></select>');
    if (options.multiple === true)
      selectList.attr('multiple', 'multiple');
    if (options.size !== undefined && options.size > 0)
      selectList.attr('size', options.size);
    /*
    if (options.size == undefined)
      selectList.attr('size', tags.size);
    */
    if (options.prompt !== undefined && options.prompt != '')
      selectList.append('<option value="" selected="selected">' + options.prompt + '</option>');
    if (typeof(options.onchange) === 'function')
      selectList.change(options.onchange);

    return selectList.append(optionList)
  }

  // namespace to hold available API methods

  $.flickr.methods = {
    // http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.tags.getListUserRaw.html
    tagSelect: function(options, select) {
      $.flickr.tags('flickr.tags.getListUserRaw', options, select)
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work. I'm sure I have missed something and would appreciate pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is broken or at least does not work as advertised. In order to get the raw version of some tags you might have to use a workaround using the flickr.tags.getListPhoto method: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.tags.getListPhoto - since you cannot pass a tag directly you will first have to do a photo search using the machine readable version, take the id of the first photo returned and pass that one to getListPhoto.